# Need add a simple blog to existing laravel site

Tags: php, laravel, blogs

Everybody . I need to add any simple blog to existing Laravel site. blog'll used for posting news(title, photo, video, description). must be tape with posts and after click to any post will open the page with all post. Also must be feature to add posts, out of the code (admin panel). Since site already done, better way looks like add any composer package, so if you know how to do it, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding your blog into Laravel (which most probably requires coding)
you can create a separated blog in WP host it on a different subdomain
and virtually add a proxy pass on your main website.

a similar case study is the following:
https://www.imghaste.com/blog/

Blog is written in Wordpress,
Main website is even hosted in a different machine.

Comment: you can user corcel package to manage your blog if you eventually go with wordpress.